# How to calculate count within the same group based on ID

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":['A','B','A','A','B','B','C','D','D','C'], 
                   'count':[1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2]})
print(df)
  ID  count
0  A      1
1  B      1
2  A      2
3  A      2
4  B      2
5  B      2
6  C      1
7  D      1
8  D      1
9  C      2
```

I will be having only `ID` column and I want to calculate `count` column. The logic is I want to cumulatively count the occurrence of an `ID`. If its repeated immediately like `index 2 & 3` they both should get same count. How can I achieve this?

My attempt which is not giving the accurate results:

```
df['x'] = df['ID'].eq(df['ID'].shift(-1)).astype(int)
df.groupby('ID')['x'].transform('cumsum')+1
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    1
7    2
8    2
9    1
Name: x, dtype: int32
```

The question is not directly related to groupby cumulative count, but it is different.

Comment: Kindly post your expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy `count` column is the expected output. I will be having only `ID` column information.

Comment: my bad. misunderstood the question. cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do `filter` then `reindex` back

```
(df[df.ID.ne(df.ID.shift())].groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1)
                            .reindex(df.index,method='ffill'))
Out[10]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    1
7    1
8    1
9    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Nice logic of using reindex and considering cumulative ID's only once.

Comment: This is very nice, and very educative. Perhaps it's possible to also add an explanation as to why this works (bit by bit) for future visitors. I know I learned a thing or two fondling around with this :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work as well:

```
df['ID'].ne(df['ID'].shift()).groupby(df['ID']).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    1
7    1
8    1
9    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `groupby()` with `sort=False`:

```
df['count2'] = df[(df.ID.ne(df.ID.shift()))].groupby('ID', sort=False).cumcount().add(1)
df['count2'] = df['count2'].ffill()
```

**Output**:

```
  ID  count  count2
0  A      1       1
1  B      1       1
2  A      2       2
3  A      2       2
4  B      2       2
5  B      2       2
6  C      1       1
7  D      1       1
8  D      1       1
9  C      2       2
```

Comment: Could you please check the output. This is not producing the correct results.

Comment: So, my output is different, but I don't know why you want 1 in index 7 and 8  and 2 in index 9, if it's 2 consecutive D's and 1 consecutive C

Comment: `why you want 1 in index 7 and 8` that is because `D` occurred for the first time there. `2 in index 9` that is because `C` occurred second time there not considering consecutive C's. If you still didn't understand, please read the question again and make sure you understand the given output in it.